# NW.js - Hiding window should bring last Application to focus

Tags: javascript, node.js, nw.js

long story short: I'm opening a window which should not quit the whole application when closing the window. That works just fine. But closing it won't return focus to the last window of the last application (like Chrome or Terminal)

```
win = nw.Window.open(
  'view.html',
  {
    width: 300,
    height: 400,
    show: false, // I show the window when DOM has been loaded.
  },
  function( win ) {
    win.setShowInTaskbar( false );

    win.on( 'close', function() {
      this.hide();
    } );
  }
);
```

Does anyone know how to give the last window it's focus back?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, what's stopping you from saving the last window's id?

```
Temp=OldWindow.id;
```

And then when you're done with the new window, restoring its focus?

```
document.getElementById(Temp).focus();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I thought of that as well, but then I was wondering how I could get the last window object. The last window object might not be from within my Application but e.g. from another one like Chrome or Firefox or whatever other Application.

Comment: If your app is not the creator of these windows then I can't see how you can have any control other than postMessage maybe.

Comment: What happens right now is, that I have my app running in the background and then via a global shortcut entering into a window. After I close the window, the previous App gets focus but not its latest window. The main menu (macOS) appears but the last window won't retrieve focus again.